# Dynamic cell height with textview and label

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, uitextview

I have some data displayed in cell (in text view)of different height for each row and a label for which i am setting frame separately. so, please can anyone tell me how to combine height of both to display them in a cell and height of text view to be dynamic.

I tried but they are overlapping.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please...could you place some code or image !!!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [UITableViewCell Dynamic Height](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/)  from the link: http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/

you can Download the demo project [Here](http://www.cimgf.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/DynamicHeights.zip).